# TCL How to remove part of the filename

Tags: tcl

All the filename is about `AA/BB/CC/N*/DD/EE`
but I need is only `N1,N2,N3`

How can I remove `AA/BB/CC/` and `/DD/EE` in TCL

`set filename [file tail $name]` ->is not available.

Thanks for help.

Comment: What do you mean that `file tail` is not available?   Surely the command is available in your Tcl interpreter.   Calling `file dirname` twice and then `file tail` would solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`file split PATH`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/file.html#M35) to split up the path into individual components, and [`lindex`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/lindex.html) to get just the bit you want:

```
#!/usr/bin/env tclsh

set filenames {AA/BB/CC/N1/DD/EE AA/BB/CC/N2/DD/EE AA/BB/CC/N3/DD/EE}

foreach name $filenames {
    set parts [file split $name]
    puts [lindex $parts 3]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for friendly help ! I can solve the problem !!

Answer (score 0):

Using `file split` and `lindex` is great if the element of interest is at a fixed index. If it isn't, `lsearch` comes into its own:

```
set filenames {AA/BB/CC/N1/DD/EE AA/BB/CC/N2/DD/EE AA/BB/CC/N3/DD/EE}

foreach name $filenames {
    set parts [file split $name]
    set part [lsearch -inline -glob $parts "N*"]
    puts $part
}
```

The `-glob` mode is actually default, but I think it helps to be specific as it reminds anyone reading the code that this is glob matching, not exact. (There's also `-regexp` for when you have a complicated pattern to match for an element.)